# redux-saga not handling multiple instances of the same actions concurrently

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm using sagas to upload a variable amount of media files. So you can dynamically add more media files. The problem that I'm running into is that when the files are getting uploaded without waiting for the previous one to complete, previous dispatched actions get lost a new one is dispatched. Basically, it's like having concurrent actions with the catch that is the same action type `UPLOAD_ACTION`.

The code is something like this:

```
export default function* root() {
  yield all([takeLatest(LOGIN_REQUEST, login), ..., takeLatest(UPLOAD_REQUEST, upload)]);
}

function* uploadSlide({payload}) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(
      uploadApi,
      payload
    );
    yield put({type: SUCCESS, payload: response});
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(type: FAILURE);
  }
}
```

I've tried different alternatives like using `takeEvery` or a `channel`, but they didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `takeLatest`, you need to use `takeEvery`. `takeEvery` Spawns a saga on each action dispatched to the Store that matches pattern.

Comment: My browser was in a weird state. Even the `debugger` was not working. After I restarted the browser `takeLatest` started working.

Comment: takeLatest spawns a saga on each action, but also cancels prior ones. takeEvery does the same but does not cancel already running sagas. That difference was unclear in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same problem when uploading many files.

Use `takeEvery` instead of `takeLatest`.

`takeLatest` is designed to cancel previous calls, which is exactly what you are suffering.

I think there is a bug in an other part of your system.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Answers need to be stand-alone since other answers can be deleted.